# A single word for "to paint and/or draw"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for "to paint and/or draw"? If you talk to artists frequently, you find you want one.

*Depict*, *portray* and similar words work in a sentence like "The artist painted/drew a horse",  but I'm looking for something that works in a sentence like "Did you paint and/or draw today?"

Comment: I just realized that what I'm asking is really: is there an intransitive verb for "to paint and/or draw"? There are plenty of transitive ones (though obviously not exact synonyms) like *depict*, *portray*, and *render*, given below.

Answer (score 5):

There is no single word that can directly replace *paint/draw* in a sentence. Painting and drawing are two distinct activities. In fact, artists who work in 2D do not only paint or draw. They make prints, do collages and much more. (I say this as someone who was once an artist.) Given your example, some options might be:

> - Did you work in the studio today?
> - Did you do any art today?

If the artist in question only paints or draws on a regular basis, then nothing beats

> - Did you paint or draw today?

Another option:

> - Are you still working on that piece?

Answer (score 4):

How about to `render`?

e.g.

```
To render in ink

"He rendered the portrait in watercolor"
```

Answer (score 2):

Although somewhat generic, *create* is a word you could use. You will have to rephrase the sentence into:

`The artist created a picture of a horse.`

Comment: I think create works fine for *did you create anything today* as well.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps...to illustrate?

"The artist illustrated a horse."

Comment: The artist **depicted** a horse.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, but "Did you depict today?" doesn't work. Read the second paragraph of the question.

Comment: "The artist illustrated a horse." Perhaps the artist painted something on the horse.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that *illustrate* works fine, and would never think that "illustrated a horse" meant you decorated the beast unless someone was using it as a pun. In the second example sentence in the original question, it would require an object, as in *Did you illustrate anything today*, or adding in an action verb and changing it to an object, as in *did you do an illustration today* or an adverb, as in *did you do any illustrating today?*

Comment: Well...I guess that's true.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of an obscure word but "limn" means to draw, paint, or depict with words.

Comment: This would benefit from a dictionary source/link for the word.

Answer (score 1):

*Very* informally, I have seen people use the term "art" as a verb. I have never seen it used outside of art gallery websites such as Deviantart.com, but on such sites, among artists, it is a pretty common term. It is almost always used to describe the self and is completely intransitive.

Tenses

- Art (I'm going to art)
- Arting (I am arting *Most common)
- Arted (I arted. *Least common form)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the word 'draw':

> Have you drawn anything today?

It's unreasonable to assume that an artist would take your question literally and leave it there.

Imagine you asked the above question, and the artist answered 'no' because he had only *painted* that day, instead of drawn, and then said nothing else. You would have to be pretty pedantic to give an answer like that, given the context.

It's far more likely that the artist would reply something along the lines of this, instead:

> 'No, but I *did* do a painting [...]'

Certainly, that's the simplest way to ask the question concisely (assuming that most artists aren't pedantic or prickly about word choice).

Answer (score -1):

Did you work on any 2D art today?

I'm not sure if you would use that sentence but that is what I would use.